# Web Service parameters' types when accessing axis2 service from .NET client

Tags: java, .net, soap, web-services, apache-axis

I have created a axis2 webservice including a method with multiple parameters:

```
class Service
{
   public void method(string a, Enum b) {
   }
}
```

When accessing with a .NET client, the code generated in the client side is:

```
void method(methodRequest request)
```

instead of having the two original parameters, and in addition methodRequest.b is of type object.

Do you know how to avoid both strange behaviors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- request/response object wrappers can be avoided making some changes to the WSDL generated by axis2. Instructions: http://pzf.fremantle.org/2007/05/handlign.html
- object type for enums is because enums are not supported yet in axis2 1.5.